# Date display sequence is not displaying up as expected in google line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have this graph on my website, it's working properly everything is okay but dates:

[image]

Dates are not showing up properly in one line they are being displayed in harmonic style. 
At first my dates were like 2013-09-01 or 2013-09-02 but they were also being displayed like this then I changed them to the current format and still the problem persists.

In PHP, I have:

```
@$previousDate2=$array[1]['previousDate'];
@$previousDate3=$array[2]['previousDate'];
@$previousDate4=$array[3]['previousDate'];
@$previousDate5=$array[4]['previousDate'];
@$previousDate6=$array[5]['previousDate'];
@$previousDate7=$array[6]['previousDate'];
@$previousDate8=$array[7]['previousDate'];
```

In above code I'm retrieving dates from MySQL Database in Y-m-d format and then after storing them inside these variables I'm formatting these variables using date_create() and date_format() functions.

```
$previousDate8=date_create($previousDate8);
$previousDate8=date_format($previousDate8, 'd/m');

$previousDate7=date_create($previousDate7);
$previousDate7=date_format($previousDate7, 'd/m');

$previousDate6=date_create($previousDate6);
$previousDate6=date_format($previousDate6, 'd/m');

$previousDate5=date_create($previousDate5);
$previousDate5=date_format($previousDate5, 'd/m');

$previousDate4=date_create($previousDate4);
$previousDate4=date_format($previousDate4, 'd/m');

$previousDate3=date_create($previousDate3);
$previousDate3=date_format($previousDate3, 'd/m');

$previousDate2=date_create($previousDate2);
$previousDate2=date_format($previousDate2, 'd/m');
```

In JavaScript, I have

```
    var date1 = "<?php echo $previousDate2; ?>";
    var date2 = "<?php echo $previousDate3; ?>";
    var date3 = "<?php echo $previousDate4; ?>";
    var date4 = "<?php echo $previousDate5; ?>";
    var date5 = "<?php echo $previousDate6; ?>";
    var date6 = "<?php echo $previousDate7; ?>";
    var date7 = "<?php echo $previousDate8; ?>";
```

and for Graph function, I have

```
  function drawVisualization() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Followers');
  data.addRows([
    [date7, follower7],
    [date6,  follower6],
    [date5,  follower5],
      [date4,  follower4],
      [date3,  follower3],
      [date2,  follower2],
      [date1,  follower1]


  ]);


    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                    width: 100+'%', 
                    height: 400,
                    vAxis: {maxValue: 10},
                    pointSize: 5}
            );
  }
```

Help needed.
Thank you

Comment: Please include the code you used to create the chart. We cannot tell if your axis is discrete or continuous, and that has the biggest impact on how the labels are displayed.

Comment: @jmac I have edited the post with code, please have a look and see if you can get me any solution. Thank you for your time

Comment: Thanks @Pallew! Glad you got an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe that the current width is still too small for those strings.
I ran your code in jsfiddle and it seemed to fit on one line when the chart became wider.

You have a couple of options:

You could make the chart wider, but given that you're already setting 100%, I suspect you're limited there.

You could use slanted text. In your options, add:

```
hAxis: {slantedText: true}
```

You can even control the angle of the slant.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e3f9S/1/

Docs here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options

Comment: To disable the up-and-down level style, you can set the maxAlternation option to 1.  It defaults to 2.  Doing that should kick in the slantedText mode automatically as needed.

Comment: @viz-tybs's solution worked. 
Thanks to viz and all of you for your help and time :-)